# Read from sql stops when I include WHERE using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a script where I would like to read from a table and list out all the "tasks" where the column check = 1. My script works fine and will list all the tasks....until I include the WHERE. Then nothing will be read into the page. What am I doing wrong?

The problem is the `WHERE check="1"`

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check="1"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
  echo $row['tasks'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

The table name is "tasks" and the two columns are "tasks" (varchar255) and "check" (int11)

Comment: Have you run the query manually, in MySQL and outside of PHP? I'd bet there are no tasks that have check="1".

Comment: Keep in mind that `check="1"` is a string compare. Now MySQL wont complain about this but sometimes you can run into strange issues when comparing variables of different type.

Write: `check = 1`

Comment: indeed...drop the quotes around the 1, as it's a number, and needs to be interpreted as such.

Comment: this is just my opinion and comment, but using a column name the same as the table name could cause confusion down the road even though it is ok to do so and functions correctly. It is my practice to never name something in the database the same unless it is referring to the same object as a foreign key.

Comment: @amaster507 yep, you could not be any more right. Anyone reading back that sql will have hell of a time figuring out who is who...

Comment: I feel as tho it's not the problem of the 1. I changed my code to SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE tasks="Task Name" and it read perfectly. Is it that I for some reason cannot read from a different column when selecting another specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Immediate problem

Why is nothing displayed? Most likely you have an SQL error. But you don't print it anywhere.

**Displaying mysql errors with PHP**

```
//this is a bad query, this time it is intentional
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check="1"');

if($sql)
{
    //do processing here, no error
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo $row['tasks'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    //output error, or handle it in any other way you like
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

And your problem is most likely quotes -- **UPDATE: on multiple levels**:

**Level 1**

- **Double quotes `"` is not ok in SQL statement.** Use single quote `'` for string constants, and backtick `` ` `` for enclosing object names (tables, columns, etc.)

**Swap quotes:**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check='1'");
```

**Escape quotes:**

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check=\'1\'');
```

- **Do you need quotes at all? this seems to be a numeric value...**

Only numeric value, no type conversion whatsoever:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check=1');
```

**Level 2**

The fact that the `check` keyword is [reserved in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) doesn't help either. You can use it to identifz objects, but with precautions: properly enclosed in backticks (`` ` ``):

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE `check`=1');
```

### Strongly consider

- leave `mysql_*` behind once and for all. Deprecated! Not Safe! Here be dragons!

  - best would be to *properly* use PDO, through prepared statements
- read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). That can be bad news any day.

  - best would be to *properly* use PDO, through prepared statements

Comment: I changed the mysql_query to your suggested above where check=1 but this is the error I got. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check=1' at line 1"

Comment: I feel as tho it's not the problem of the 1. I changed my code to SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE tasks="Task Name" and it read perfectly. Is it that I for some reason cannot read from a different column when selecting another specifically?

Comment: Sorry for not responding, been busy lately... I found the issue: the `check` is a reserved keyword in MySQL... So I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check='1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $row['tasks'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

but you can try something like `SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check = 1`,

Comment: @MarcB I don't think so. `1='1'` might be true (but still slower than necessary). `1="1"` is syntax error. And he did mention mysqli, which is at least not deprecated...

Comment: nope. it's not a syntax error, unless mysql's running in sql_mode=ANSI. standard mysql allows such a comparison, and will typecast the values as needed. `select 1="1"` returns `1` in normal operation mode, and `unknown column` in ANSI mode. But again, ansi mode is not the default operation mode for mysql.

Comment: @MarcB while I have no doubts you are not a beginner, [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19170) seems to go against it... Ok, it is a specific version of MySQL, and even Jon Skeet only knows how it is configured when he _really_ wants that, but I doubt the guys at SQLFiddle would configure the sql_mode different than the default value... (By the way, [according to this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19173) sql_mode was STRICT_TRANS_TABLES in the fiddle case...)

Comment: @MarcB And [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19175) shows, the default value for sql_mode (empty) is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, as ppeterka said, you don't need quotes at all:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT tasks FROM tasks WHERE check=1');
```

Consider also that using quotes will prevent your query from following an eventual index on "check" column.